# Python: Printing grid of varying sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, grid

I am working on a function to get a grid to print out depending on user-input. So far I was able to get it to print a simple version where it changed sizes for example:

```
print_grid(15) 
#prints a larger grid:
+ - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - +
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
+ - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - +
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
|               |               |
+ - - - - - - - + - - - - - - - +
```

But now I am trying to do something so that it can accept two input variables (x, y) where x is the number of rows/columns (area) and y is the size of the individual, smaller grids within the larger whole. For example, print_grid2(3,4) results in:

```
+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +
|         |         |         |
|         |         |         |
|         |         |         |
|         |         |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +
|         |         |         |
|         |         |         |
|         |         |         |
|         |         |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +
|         |         |         |
|         |         |         |
|         |         |         |
|         |         |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - + - - - - +
```

I reused some of my code from the first grid example and then changed it to try to accommodate this specific task, but I don't get any output this time and am not sure what is going on if I am getting nothing as output... Any help is appreciated. (I haven't updated my comments yet, so I realize that they are not making sense anymore since they relate to the previous iteration).

Current Code:

```
def grid_print(area, units):

   print_Area = (area * area)

   grid_rows = units + (units + 1) + 2

   grid_cols = units + 2

   if units % 2 == 0:           # If grid entry is even (it will end up making
        grid_rows += 1               # the square uneven, so increase number of rows by 1
                            # now grid is technically uneven
        for i in range(print_Area):
           for row in range(grid_rows):     # for each item in number of items(rows)
               for col in range(grid_cols): # for each item in number of items(columns)
                   if row == 0 or row == int(grid_rows/2) or row == grid_rows -1:    # if item is beginning, middle or end
                   # --  Formatting beam structure  -- #
                       if col == 0:                        # beginning, print '+' no '\n'
                           print('+', end='')
                       elif col == grid_cols -1:                # end, print '+'
                       print('+')
                       elif int(grid_cols/2) == col:            # middle:
                           if grid_rows % 2 == 0:               # if grid is even, pad '+' with ' '
                               print(' + ', end='')        # if grid is uneven, no padding
                           else:                           # print '+' no '\n'
                               print('+', end='')
                       elif col % 2 == 0:                  # if col item is an even number
                           print('-', end='')              # print '-' with no '\n'
                       else:                               # else if col item is uneven item num
                           print(' ', end='')              # print ' ' no '\n'
                   else:
                   # --  Formatting line structure  -- #
                       if col == 0:                        # if column is at starting position 0
                           print('|', end='')              # print '|' no '\n'
                       elif col == int(grid_cols/2):            # if column is at middle pos
                           if units % 2 == 0:               # print '|' no '\n'
                               print(' | ', end='')        # (has padding if grid is even or not)
                           else:
                               print('|', end='')
                       elif col == grid_cols -1:                # if column is at end position of grid
                           print("|")                      # print '|'
                       else:
                           print(' ', end='')              # all other circumstances, print ' ' no '\n'
```

Comment: How are the rules? Where to 3 and 4 occur in the example? 3x3 with 4x4 cells?

Comment: Maybe wrong indentation? You indent every thing after `if units % 2 == 0:`

Comment: Sorry! I updated my post to include better details on the intended outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in your code is probably just an indentation error after `if units % 2 == 0:`, but your entire code can be compressed to these line:

```
def print_grid(area, unit):
    for _ in range(area):
        print(("+" + "- " * unit) * area + "+")
        for _ in range(unit):
            print(("|" + "  " * unit) * area + "|")
    print(("+" + "- " * unit) * area + "+")


print_grid(3, 4)
```

prints:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This certainly does work within the limited parameters I provided, so I apologize for not providing further details from the outset. The function, ideally, will be able to take in two input variables (x, y) where x is the number of rows/columns and y is the size of the individual, smaller grids within the larger whole.

Comment: @McBraunie This function does that. Do you have any problems with this approach?